# fgets() is failing to read data from the fail and leading the program to a halt. The program is stuck there forever

Tags: c, linux, embedded, file-handling, fgets

I am opening a file and reading the data from the file using fgets() and this is done every scan. For the first 10 times the data is read correctly but when after a couple of scans fgets() fails to read the data from the file. I verified if the data is even present in the file by placing "cat ../file" which is showing the contents of the file but somehow not being passed to fgets(), I dont know why.

The following is a snippet of the code :

```
system("cat /sys/bus/temp1_input"); //displaying the right data
if(fd= fopen("/sys/bus/temp1_input","r"))
{
    if(fgets (val_str, 10, fd)!=NULL)
        temp_val = atoi(val_str);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

The controller is just stuck at fgets() and does not move past that which has been verified by placing the prints before and after the fgets().

Is it possibly because I am continuously opening and closing? what could be the possible issue for the fgets() not getting the data?

In order to solve the issue of the controller from getting stuck, the above code has been converted into NON-BLOCKING code but at the end of the day fgets() should read the data if the content is present in the file right?

Also, the file pointer does not got to NULL and is perfectly fine.

Comment: fgets returns when you either get the number of characters requested, or a newline, or end-of-file is reached.  If none of those happens then it will wait.

Comment: Is /sys/bus/temp1_input a regular file?

Comment: it's not a regular file. It has the temperature of the CPU.

Comment: @EashaJilakar Post definition of `val_str`.  Please also post some sample data read.

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example, including `main()`, `val_str`,  all the includes you do, .... ? (make the example as short as possible).

Comment: Tested it with `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/temp1_input` and it showed a valid temperature 200 times in a row.

Comment: @stark `fgets()` also returns if a read error occurs. Concerning "get the number of characters requested", that is one less than 10, or 9, in OP's case.